# Underline effect for graph and text using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Do you know how to add the **yellow** **highlight** effect of this 538 graph for both text and graphs using ggplot2?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably be easiest to export the chart as a vector graphic and edit it in something like Adobe illustrator

Comment: Agreed Robin. I think that’s what they did.

Answer (score 3):

**Update after clarification**

It really depends on the structure of the data and what you are using to plot. However, if you wanted to add large highlights to particular plots, then you could plot the same `geom_line` but change the aesthetics of it (though the highlight will not connect to adjacent plots).

```
library(ggplot2)

hlines <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(MN = min(wt))

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt), colour = "lightyellow", size = 80) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_hline(
    data = hlines,
    aes(yintercept = MN),
    linetype = "dotted",
    color = "grey",
    size = 1.5
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

For text, in `ggplot2`, you can add fill to the background of annotations. But it again really depends on the structure and how you are plotting the text. You could split up the annotations, so that you could `fill` one and not the other part of the text.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt), colour = "lightyellow", size = 80) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 30,
    y = 5,
    label = "It hasn't really dropped off"
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "label",
    x = 30,
    y = 4.75,
    label = "since he first won office in 2016",
    fill = "lightyellow",
    label.size = NA
  )
```

Output

[image]

**First Answer**
It depends on what exactly you are looking for/what your data looks like. But if you are wanting to place a line at the minimum under a line graph in a faceted plot, then you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

hlines <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(MN = min(wt))

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_hline(
    data = hlines,
    aes(yintercept = MN),
    linetype = "dotted",
    color = "grey",
    size = 1.5
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

If you just have a single plot, then you can use `geom_hline` and just provide the y intercept.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5,
    linetype = "dotted",
    color = "grey",
    size = 1.5
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but my question is about the actual yellow underline (as if it was a highlighter) rather than the line itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PabloAB Yeah, I definitely missed that part. I'm not sure of a way to draw across several plots. But I've updated my answer to show at least one possibility for highlighting a given plot and also part of a text annotation. Another option would be to turn a `ggplot` object into a `grob`, then you could add a shape around multiple plots to highlight, though it would not give the highlighter effect like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Really cool solution! One could add some auto correlated noise to make the highlighting look more organic

Comment: instead of using geom = "label", you could use geom = "text" for the first bit, this saves you then two lines of code ;)